# Recursive make loses status code

Tags: shell, makefile

I have the following makefile structure

```
$  cat makefile
foo:
        $(MAKE) -C bar barbaz

$  cat bar/makefile
barbaz:
        exit 111
```

When I make the target foo I would expect the status code 111 but instead I get status code 2:

```
$  make foo
make -C bar barbaz
make[1]: Entering directory `bar'
exit 111
make[1]: *** [barbaz] Error 111
make[1]: Leaving directory `bar'
make: *** [foo] Error 2
```

How can I have the outer make fail with "Error 111" instead of "Error 2"?

BTW: I'm using GNU Make 3.81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue with recursive `make` invocation; that is a red herring.

If you simply do this from the shell:

```
$ make barbaz # in bar directory
exit 111
make[1]: *** [barbaz] Error 111
$ echo $?
2
```

Make isn't propagating the exact exit status of the failing recipe.

This is documented here:

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Running.html

> *"The exit status of make is always one of three values: [...]'*

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  GNU make always uses a well-defined set of status codes, and those are the only ones it will exit with.  It will never exit with the exit code of a command that it invoked.  For details see [How to Run Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Running.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is one command in one recipe what exits with code `111`, not `make` itself.

`make` exits with code `2`.